# Were owened/ had been owned/ have been owned

Tags: tense

I have a difficulty know which tense I should use in this case.

I am to state factual information, what should I say?

> in 2011, only 46% of the houses *were rented/ have been rented/ had been rented.*

What tense should I use?

Answer (score 3):

We assume that you are about to make this statement at present about a situation that existed seven years ago.

Therefore, the situation is in the past and you would normally say:

> In 2011 only 46% of houses *were* rented.

However, you might wish to add something to the sentence that suggested the past perfect tense:

> In 2011 only 46% of houses had been rented before the government changed the rental laws.

Here, the use of *had been* emphasizes that the percentage of rented houses was measured before the legislation came into effect.

Many English speakers would simply say that the houses *were* rented before the government changed the rental laws. It's optional. The *past perfect* merely underlines the sequence of events.

If you were talking about the percentage of houses rented so far this year, you would say:

> In 2018 only 46% of houses *have been* rented.

as it is still 2018 and the houses are still being rented.

So we are talking about a situation that began some months ago and is still current today.

Answer (score 1):

When the time-phrase in a clause excludes the present, you cannot use the present perfect.

> **In 2011** <sup>time-phrase</sup>, only 46% of the houses **have been rented**. <sup>NO</sup>

However, if the phrase "in 2011" does not refer to a time, but to a label on a chart, say, then this rule does not apply:

> As you can see from the chart, in 2011 only 46% of the houses have been rented.

There "in 2011" is not strictly speaking a time-phrase, but a reference to a label on a chart. The reference is to the data on the chart before us now, the one we are examining *at this moment*, and in that case the present perfect is a valid choice.